# creating stub for after_create hook in rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

my model code is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_node_for_user

   def create_node_for_user
     UserGraph.create(user_id: self.id)
   end
end
```

and test for User model:

```
it "create node in graph database on user creation" do
  userr = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  UserGraph.should_receive(:create).with(user_id: userr.id)
  userr.save
end
```

but my test is failing with message

```
Failure/Error: userr.save
   <UserGraph (class)> received :create with unexpected arguments
     expected: ({:user_id=>nil})
          got: ({:user_id=>94})
```

what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that the `userr` you build with FactoryGirl does not have an ID. Thats why the expectation tells you that you expected `:user_id=>nil`. The ID will be generated when AR saves the record, so there is no way that you can guess the generated ID ahead of time. You could use a less restrictive assertion on the mock:

```
UserGraph.should_receive(:create).with(hash_including(:user_id))
```

This will verify that a hash is passed with a `:user_id` key. You can find more about `hash_including` here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers:hash_including

Another thing you can try (not sure if it works) is to match against the `kind_of` matcher of rspec. This would make sure that a number was passed with `:user_id`

```
UserGraph.should_receive(:create).with(:user_id => kind_of(Numeric))
```

Answer (score 3):

The explanation given by Yves is correct: the user id is nil until the record is saved because it is autogenerated by the DB.  Here's an alternate approach:

```
it "create node in graph database on user creation" do
  userr = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

  create_args = nil
  UserGraph.should_receive(:create) { |*args| create_args = args }
  userr.save

  expect(create_args).to eq(:user_id => userr.id)
end
```

Essentially, this moves the expectation about what the arguments should be so that it comes *after* the record has been saved, when the record has an `id`.

Comment: can you explain this line `UserGraph.should_receive(:create) { |*args| create_args = args }`

Comment: Yep. The block is a way of handling the `create` message with arbitrary code (see https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#arbitrary-handling).  When `UserGraph` receives the `create` message, it will run the provided block. Within the block, I'm storing the arguments provided with the `create` message in a local variable so that I can set an expectation on it later, at the end of the example.